# How do I remap the Caps Lock and Ctrl keys?

Tags: keyboard, vim

I'd like to remap my keys such that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> behaves as the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key and vice-versa. Also, if possible I'd like the settings to be available only within the currently logged-in user. How can I achieve this?

I'm a vim user, unlike the other people who use this machine, so I'd like those settings only for my account.

Comment: Does [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203) help?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2013/12/where-should-control-key-be.html

Comment: I'm appalled that this is not a standard feature in Linux settings in this day and age.

Comment: Same question on SuperUser: [keyboard - How to swap ctrl and caps lock using xmodmap - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/268269/how-to-swap-ctrl-and-caps-lock-using-xmodmap)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**13.10+:**

Install and use `gnome-tweak-tool` > `Keyboard & Mouse` > `Keyboard` > `Additional Layout Options` > `Caps Lock behavior`.

**Pre 13.10:**

Open the Keyboard Preferences dialog (`System -> Preferences -> Keyboard`).  On the layout tab, click the `Options...` button.  Expand the `Ctrl key position` section and select `Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock`.

Those settings should be applied each time you log in, and will only affect your user account.

Comment: This option has disappeared in Ubuntu Saucy. I'm not sure how to explain this but it is simply not there. The Keyboard preferences have no "Layout tab", but there is a "layout settings" button, and when I click it it takes me to the "Input Sources" tab of the "Region & Language" panel, which is mysteriously lacking any kind of 'Options' button. The only button there opens up a virtual on-screen keyboard that displays my broken keyboard layout to me with no way of changing which keys behave which way.

Comment: For Ubuntu 13.10, you'll need to use gnome-tweak-tool.

Comment: Pre 13.10 option works for me in 14.04

Comment: Same as @JeremyKun. In my case, using 14.04, the pre 13.10 solution worked but the 13.10+ didn't

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The `gnome-tweak-tool` is really nice; you can also use it for niceties like "use Caps Lock for switching keyboard layouts" (a personal favourite) and "switch Alt/Win" (which is useful if you've been a long-time Mac user...)

Comment: Thank you. My control key broke on one keyboard, so I went for the option "Ctrl is mapped to Win and the usual Ctrl keys", which makes it work perfectly on either keyboard.

Comment: There's no "Keyboard & Mouse" -> "Additional Layout Options" in gnome 3.34

Comment: Install `gnome-tweaks`, and instead of *Caps Lock behavior*, pick *Ctrl position* and select *Swap ctrl and Caps Lock*. That way we can still use Caps Lock when needed.

Comment: Still works in 23.10. Thank you! Gnome tweaks are available via apt.

Answer (score 91):

Here's a way to do it without installing extra software:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:swapcaps
```

Source:

- http://www.noah.org/wiki/CapsLock_Remap_Howto

Comment: This doesn't survive after reboot. How can I make this permanent? I'd rather not put this in a startup script (e.g. .bashrc).

Comment: @nic You need to also change the file `sudo vi /etc/default/keyboard` and change `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"`. Run Jorge's command after that but as `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` such that it does not change your default keyboard layout.

Comment: This also doesn't survive after wake up from suspend.

Comment: This some how changed my left windows key to caps lock...

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: This is how I used to do it too but it doesn't seem to work with the latest LTS (22.04.3).  As an interesting bonus pushing caps lock (to either lock or unlock) also dims my screen one notch

Answer (score 72):

One of the best ways to do that graphically if you are using the GNOME shell is to install **Gnome Tweak Tool**:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

**For version 3.30.0 and later:**

- Open tweak-tool and click on the *Keyboard & Mouse* section in the left menu bar.
- Click on the *Additional Layout Options* button on the left.
- Under *Caps Lock behavior* select *Caps Lock is also a Ctrl*.

**For older versions:**

- Open tweak-tool and click on the *typing* section in the left column.
- You should now see the line *Caps Lock key behavior* on the left.
- Choose *Make Caps Lock an additional Ctrl key* instead of *Disabled* in the drop-down list and you should be good.

Enjoy your new <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key!

Comment: I wanted to use my CAPS key to turn my screen off. I set this up before in the System Settings > keyboard window, but the CAPS still toggled CapsLock state and LED. So I disabled the key with the tool you recommended (which has some display errors btw. - transparent window background), which also stopped my custom shortcut from working. After disabling, I had to set the shortcut again to have it work. It got set to the value 0xff or something like this instead of CAPS. I thought this procedure might help some future readers with similar wishes.

Comment: When I run gnome-tweak-tool from the command line, there's an error message about shell not running DBus and then any attempts I make to change settings have no effect.

Comment: Update: gnome-tweak-tool only works inside the gnome shell

Comment: no "typing" section in my left-hand column: only Desktop, Fonts, Shell, Shell Extensions, Theme, Windows.

Comment: Note the option in gnome-tweak-tool to swap is under "Ctrl key position", not "Caps Lock key behavior".

Comment: I found it under "Keyboard & Mouse" -> "Additional Layout Options" -> "Caps Lock Behavior" -> "Caps lock is also a Ctrl".

Comment: tweak-tool doesn't work if you use e.g. VNC Viewer

Comment: There's no "Keyboard & Mouse" -> "Additional Layout Options" in gnome 3.34

Comment: @Marius Strangely, I have just checked in Gnome Tweak Tools 3.34.0 (under GNOME Shell 3.36.6), and the *Keyboard & Mouse* menu is still there, with an *Additional Layout Options* button in it.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much @PierreThalamy ! It is there, as a button. I was looking for a section, similar to Mouse, Touchpad...

Answer (score 61):

Open the following for editing:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/keyboard
```

And edit `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"`

Then, reconfigure:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

or

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"
```

Comment: The question was "I'd like those settings only for my account."  Editing /etc/default/keyboard is going to change it for everyone.

Comment: you have 3 steps (1, 2, 3). Do you mean [(1 and 2) or 3] or [1 and (2 or 3)]?

Comment: Great! Ran the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and press several enters, and it worked!!!   EDIT: however, after i log out and log back in, the setting went away. :(

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. It sets it system-wide and for both command-line and X11.

Comment: How do I turn it back off? I tried simply going back to `XKBOPTIONS=""` and reboot and then that, reconfigure, and reboot, but no such luck.

Answer (score 30):

To permanently change the behaviour:

1. run `dconf-editor`
2. select `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources`
3. Change `xkb-options` to `['ctrl:nocaps']` (or add it to any existing options)

or on the command line (*Warning -- this overwrites your existing settings!*):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:nocaps']"
```

Comment: This one liner can also be added to ~/.profile for portability.

Comment: This did not work for me on Kubuntu 16.04, even after a reboot.

Comment: dconf settings apply immediately and are persistent, so it makes no sense to put it in ~/.profile and there is no need for a reboot. This particular setting only applies to Gnome/Unity, not KDE that is used in Kubuntu.

Answer (score 12):

This is how to do it manually (without additional tools), via XKB, which is the default keys manager for recent Ubuntus.
Modify `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` , section `xkb_symbols "pc105"`:

```
//key <CAPS> {  [ Caps_Lock     ]   };
//key <LCTL> {  [ Control_L     ]   };
key <CAPS> {    [ Control_L ]   };
key <LCTL> {    [ Caps_Lock     ]   };
```

Login/logout or reboot.

Alternatively you can swap at the level of keycodes that are emitted by those buttons. Modify `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` :

```
<CAPS> = 64; //66;
<LCTL> = 66; //64
```

You'll need to `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*` to apply the changes.

Comment: Great point about working at the level of the keycodes. On my laptops running Kubuntu Bionic, merely changing at the symbols level isn't satisfactory because pressing the physical Caps key still toggles the internal Caps state. Changing the keycodes works! BTW I extended this to three keys (Caps, Meta and RAlt) and would like to note that you actually need to write `<CAPS> = *orig code of the physical key you want to act **as** CAPS*` rather than `<CAPS> = *orig code of the key you want physical CAPS to act **as**` (I hope the distinction is clear). This distinction is needed in such cases.

Comment: This is very good answer because it changes the map in the lower level, other answer have issues when connecting different keyboards or Bluetooth ones. This one does not suffer form that

Comment: If you have lets say a laptop with an extra external bluetooth keyboard the `evdev` patching is the one that will work for ALL they keyboards, sadly the `/etc/default/keyboard` didn't for me on ubuntu 20

Comment: Some how this did not work for me. Neither option worked.  CAPs  is still caps and ctrl no longer works.

Comment: I also have issue on Ubuntu 22, where regular Control_L still works, but Caps_Lock now does nothing.

Comment: I didn't want to switch the caps-lock with the left-control. I just wanted to turn the capslock into a control key. I just changed the `key <CAPS> {    [ Control_L ]   };` entry as suggested and it works great. I like this solution better than the gnone-tweaks solution that I had been using with previous computers.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is confusing because gnome-tweak-tools doesn't show any "typing" section.

Instead, click on "Keyboard & Mouse" section and then choose "Additional Layout Option". There, you will see "Caps Lock behavior" which allows converting caps lock to different keys.

[image]

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, there is also the section `Ctrl position' -> 'Caps Lock as Ctrl'

Answer (score 4):

This is an easy task once you know how to do it.

1) Check the keycode of yours key. Run this program at terminal.

```
xev
```

[image]
At this example, the terminal shows that the keycode for my <kbd>k</kbd> is "45".

2) Change them as you like creating this file:

```
gedit ~/.Xmodmap
```

It's contents should look like this example:

keycode  37 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
keycode  66 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L

(Change the keycode number as needed - look at step "1")

Ilustration:
[image]
(Obs.: if I want to change my <kbd>k</kbd> I should use "keycode 45" as showed at step "1").

4) Logout and log back in or reboot or run this:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Hope you enjoy ;-)

Comment: Note that this solution is likely to cause problems for anything but the simplest keymaps.  The xmodmap compatibility in the newer xkb system is not perfect, so you're probably better off sticking to xkb if possible.

Comment: @James would you like to explain how can we do that?

Comment: See the other answer to this question.  The standard keyboard control panel will construct and xkb keymap from the base layout you pick plus the options you enable.

Comment: @James Thank you very much. So I guess we should only play with keymaps when 'System -> Preferences -> Keyboard' doesn't have a solution for what we want, right?

Comment: Well, you can set up the same keymaps using the command line `setxkbmap` program.  Writing new keymaps is possible, but a bit more involved than Xmodmap keycode mappings.  It is a good thing that most of the option variants you'd want are already available.

Comment: @James. I have been searching and learning about setxkbmap. But I couldn't find an answer for: is it possible to remap a key to anything we want? For example something eccentric like: "keycode 51 = bracketright braceright bracketright braceright masculine bar"?

Answer (score 4):

On KDE-based distributions (like KDE Neon or Kubuntu) this behavior can be configured in the regular system settings. Open the system settings, select "Input Devices" => "Keyboard" => "Advanced". In the category "Ctrl key position" select "Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock".

[image: Screenshot of KDE's System Setting's Keyboard module]

Answer (score 1):

gnome-tweaks 3.28.1 has no `Typing` section.
Thus, `setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:nocaps` or `setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:swapcaps` would be feasible options.

To make it permanent, you can refer to the answer of @name.

Comment: Keyboard& mouse -> additional layout option

Comment: It is not feasible to change the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using i3, you can add this to your i3 config:

`exec_always "setxkbmap -layout au -option ctrl:swapcaps"`

This will make it that the keys are always swapped on i3 load.

Answer (score 0):

trough tweaks don't work together

- swap Ctrl and Caps Lock
- switch to another layout by Caps Lock

find solution:

- Caps Lock as Ctrl
- switch to another layout by Left Ctrl
- both Shift together enable Caps Lock

Answer (score 0):

To have capslock behave as a ctrl at all times, I had to do the following.

For the behavior in the gnome session, use `gnome-tweaks`.
For the behavior at the login screen and in text-only sessions, do the following.

Edit /etc/default/keyboard and set:

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"
```

Then

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh console-setup
```

And finally, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to make the Caps Lock key an additional Ctrl key, just type this in the terminal as your user:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:ctrl_modifier']"

# or you can use dconf
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['caps:ctrl_modifier']"
```

To make sure the setting is effective:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```