# Does Ubuntu have the ABNT2 Brazilian layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

In version ubuntu 12.04 does not come with the keyboard to ABNT2 Brazilian?

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Try to type `setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br`, or alternatively, reconfigure the keyboard, following the instructions of the command `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. You only have to check the Layout list and look for Brazillian. Go to System Settings, then Region and Language, *Layouts*. Hit the + symbol:

[image]

In the search box type Brazil

[image]

Select **Portuguese (Brazil, eliminate dead keys)**, then click **Add**. Done.

This is how the Layout looks like.

[image]

Comment: On the abnt2 the question mark is in the left before the shift key (google abnt2 images)
None of the options on ubuntu worked for me.
What worked was running this on the terminal:
```
setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2 -option deadkeys
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br` works. However, it is not consistent after reboot or logging off.

Based on this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66657/448527) and also this [one](https://askubuntu.com/a/633539/996439):

1. Install `sudo apt install dconf-editor`
2. Run `dconf-editor`
3. Select *org.gnome.desktop.input-sources*
4. Add `[('xkb', 'br'), ('xkb', 'br+abnt2')]` to Custom Value

You can use `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` to check if the configurations were successfully saved.

This is my keyboard layout:

[image]