# How can I remap caps-lock to caps-lock after unmapping it?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

How do I remap caps-lock to caps-lock, preferably via bash? I mistakenly used the following command while in caps-lock was active:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:nocaps
```

I am trapped in caps-lock now. This happens to me about once every other month. I usually use the naive approach of rebooting my computer to fix this issue. I would like a better solution. I need to temporarily undo the above bash command, so that I can turn off caps-lock.

see: [How do I remap the Caps Lock and Ctrl keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33774/how-do-i-remap-the-caps-lock-and-ctrl-keys)

Alternative solutions:

1. a bash command that toggles caps lock on/off.
2. any other keyboard tricks that turn off caps-lock without caps-lock. I already tried the on-screen keyboard, but it contains no caps-lock key.

Comment: The Problem is persistent, even after a reboot? `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: No, I reboot the system to resolve this issue, but that is a naive solution. I would instead like a bash command to turn caps-lock off, or a bash command to remap caps-lock to caps-lock. Thanks!

Comment: `setxkbmap -option caps:` might work, but it sporadically fails for me, will investigate later.

Comment: Solution: `setxkbmap -layout us -option`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Linux Mint](https://securitronlinux.com/bejiitaswrath/how-to-toggle-the-caps-lock-key-with-the-command-line-in-linux-mint/):

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Then toggle the caps lock key with this command:

```
xdotool key Caps_Lock
```

Run this command again to turn caps lock off.

Comment: This is one solution, but a more universal one would be one that does not require root or packages.

Comment: Root is only required to install package one time. Do not repeat command after already installed.

Comment: i DO NOT HAVE ROOT PERMISSION. i ESSENTIALLY NEED TO DO THE REVERSE OF: setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:nocaps