# How do I map caps and control to control

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I tried [the solution here](https://askubuntu.com/a/418773/370960) to remap Caps Lock to Control.

> Open the following for editing:
>
> `sudo vi /etc/default/keyboard`
>
> And edit `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"`
>
> Then, reconfigure:
>
> `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

I started with exactly that not to get too crazy. It worked. But now I can't get  it to go back.

I edited the keyboard file back to its original contents...

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

... but even after rebooting, caps is still control and control is still caps.

Where should I look to set things back?

What should I do to get *both* Control and Caps to invoke Control?

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: @guiverc I did both. Edited and rebooted, then edited, ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and then rebooted. In the reconfigure flow, I just accepted every default -- not sure if there was something else I needed to do, but I think that was right.

Comment: So I've [followed this guide](https://fostips.com/remap-keys-ubuntu-22-04/) and set everything up with Tweaks, which does work. It even saw that I had Caps Lock and Control swapped. I'm not sure what file it edited to get that working, though, as the `keyboard` file still has the contents I pasted, above.

Comment: It probably propagated to your user level settings: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson That gives `['caps:ctrl_modifier']`, fwiw, which is what we'd expect, I believe.

Comment: Yes, and to reset it you can simply do: `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Appreciate the help. Seems to be a disconnect here; my apologies. For instance, "_but even after rebooting, caps is still control and control is still caps_"; what did I do incorrectly? You don't mention `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` specifically. Is that required or a red herring? etc My assumption is that the steps above didn't work (b/c they didn't for me -- could be PIBKAC, could be instructions; trying to find out which). What are the right ones? etc etc Thanks again.

Comment: When you first added a value to `XKBOPTIONS` in `/etc/default/keyboard`, that value automatically was added to your user settings at next login. When you changed `/etc/default/keyboard` back to its original content, the value was still kept in your user settings. You you should have run the reset command too, as I mentioned above, to also drop the value from your user settings. Alternatively you could have dropped it using Tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

- Install the `gnome-tweaks` package, if it's not already installed.
- Open *Tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Ctrl position*
- Uncheck the "Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock" option.
- Check the "Caps Lock as Ctrl" option.

Comment: So, as [I mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455915/how-do-i-map-caps-and-control-to-control/1455998#comment2545019_1455915), I tried that and it worked, but I wanted to figure out what and how it solved the problem. If the secret is to get `['caps:ctrl_modifier']` in there, what did I do wrong initially and how should I edit that outside of Tweaks?

Comment: @ruffin: I thought those questions were answered implicitly. What you need to keep in mind is that there are two levels for setting XKB options: system wide (in `/etc/default/keyboard`) and per user via Tweaks or the `gsettings` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use the config below.

```
[ids]

*

[main]

capslock = layer(control)
```